# Can Google Analytics be linked to a Search Console property set?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

My site is available as either:

- `http://example.com/`
- `https://example.com/`

Users can choose which to use.   I have both added as properties in Google Search Console and the two show different data in search analytics.

I have created a "property set" in Google Search Console called "Example" that has both HTTP and HTTPS versions in it.   It shows the combined data of both in search analytics.

Is it possible to link Google Analytics with this combined property set so that I can get all the search analytics data from Search Console into Google Analytics?

Comment: For what it is worth, property sets are dead as of March 2019:  [Property Sets No Longer Supported In Google Search Console](https://www.seroundtable.com/property-sets-no-longer-supported-in-google-search-consol-27169.html)

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics won't let you link to a property set, only to individual properties. You can however pick the more popular URL of the two to get reasonably accurate data.

BTW, it is advisable to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. The redirect will prevent duplicate content issues and it helps with security.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion that it can't be done.   I'm not sure why though, and I can't find and documentation from Google stating that they don't support it.  Property sets just don't seem to appear in list of Search Console properties that can be linked.