# Google Search Console domain property not in the list of properties I can add to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, domains

I'm trying to connect a domain property to a google analytics domain. But when the property I added is not in the list of properties where I can choose from.

All the other properties are. The big difference is that the newly added property is a domain property. All the others are regular properties. Is there a new way to connect this domain properties to google analytics?

Comment: See also [Can Google Analytics be linked to a Search Console property set?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/can-google-analytics-be-linked-to-a-search-console-property-set).  Domain properties are a replacement for property sets.   Property sets could not be connected to GA.

Comment: But I thought these domain properties are the new standard so you don't have to insert 4 properties for one domain. Is this something that will be available in the future? Or should I just go back from domain properties to the old properties?

Comment: [Google Says Long Term Plan You Should Switch To Domain Properties](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-switch-to-domain-properties-27333.html) but they may not be fully functional yet.  I'm hoping Google has this issue on their radar, but as far as I know, we haven't heard anything from them about it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the Domain Property, also create and verify a single prefix url property in GSC and use it to link to your GA property. Make sure the prefix-url property is for the correct version of the domain.

More info on prefix-url and domain properties
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en