# How to link new Google Analytics (version 4) property with Search Console?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

I just created the other day a Google Analytics property for a new website, and it was created using the new Analytics version (v4). Now I'm trying to link it to my existing Search Console account for that website, but cannot find a way to do so. I go to "Admin" / "Property" / "Product linking", and I don't see Search Console there:

[image: Google Analytics setup]

How can I link them both? Or... is it necessary at all with the new Google Analytics? Does it have other features that make up for it?

Comment: My guess is that Google hasn't implemented the linking with GA4 yet.    They have a history of making changes that are not compatible with linking.  See [Can Google Analytics be linked to a Search Console property set?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/can-google-analytics-be-linked-to-a-search-console-property-set) and  [Google Search Console domain property not in the list of properties I can add to Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122242/google-search-console-domain-property-not-in-the-list-of-properties-i-can-add-to)

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to add: my Search Console property is a domain property. It's just a simple site (only one page, barely an online brochure), which is why I only created it. Should I create a site property then?

Comment: If you want the link to Google analytics, even the older version, you'll need a prefix property in addition to your domain property. I don't know if GA4 supports linking at all yet though.

Comment: I have a lot of issues with the GA4 experience so far, personally I've gone back to the OG

Answer (score 5):

GA4 Properties are still not linkable.

Having said that, the method for linking GA to GSC has changed and it's now referred to as an Association.
For GA, it must be done from within the GSC interface, not from within GA.

As of Feb 2021 you can now link GSC *domain* properties to GA (it's now recommended).

To get to the GSC Associations page:
https://search.google.com/search-console/settings/associations

> You can associate your Google Analytics property with your Search
> Console property to see Search Console data directly in Google
> Analytics.
>
> Any Search Console data exported from Search Console to your
> associated Google Analytics property will be subject to the Google
> Analytics terms of service. At the same time, any data exported from
> your Google Analytics property to your associated Search Console
> property will be subject to the Search Console terms of service.
>
> *Learn how to associate your Google Analytics property with your Search Console property.*
>
> When you associate a Search Console property with a Google Analytics
> property, Search Console data is enabled for all reporting views
> associated with that property by default. As a result, anybody with
> access to that Google Analytics property or one of its views may be
> able to see Search Console data for that site. For example, if a
> Google Analytics administrator adds a user to property or view, that
> user may be able to see Search Console data in Search Optimization
> reports.
>
> Google Analytics account administrators can move their Analytics
> property from one Analytics account to another. Any associated Search
> Console properties will maintain their association as part of the
> move. After the move, any users of the new Analytics account will be
> able to see data from the associated Search Console property without
> anotification in Search Console.

Full documentation on GSC Associations can be found here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9419894

Comment: If it helps this is still relevant as of Oct '21. *sigh

Answer (score 3):

As of now, Google recommends creating both UA and GA4 properties together. So this linking is not possible at the moment

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/77936816/linking-search-console-to-ga4?hl=en